# how to detect if a user open a page in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i am making an chat app and want to add a "seen" option in it, to do so i want to know when the user open's the page 
 i dont have any idea of this these are my routes

```
class Routes {
  final routes = <String, WidgetBuilder>{
  '/auth': (BuildContext context) => AuthScreen(),
  '/home': (BuildContext context) => HomeScreen(),
  '/profile/edit': (BuildContext context) => EditUserScreen(),
  '/': (BuildContext context) => SplashScreen(),
  '/phonelog': (BuildContext context) => MobileAuthScreen(),
  '/Chat': (BuildContext context) => Chat(),
};
```

Comment: what kind of state management are you using?

Comment: statefulwidgets

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example:

You can add a model during the route creation, or you can provide it if you use any kind of service locator or inherited widget.

Than just add to that model a flag that you have seen the route.

```
class Routes {
  final routes;
  final RouteModel routeModel;

  Routes()
      : routeModel = RouteModel(),
        routes = <String, WidgetBuilder>{
          '/auth': (BuildContext context) => AuthScreen(routeModel),
          '/home': (BuildContext context) => HomeScreen(routeModel),
          '/profile/edit': (BuildContext context) => EditUserScreen(routeModel),
          '/': (BuildContext context) => SplashScreen(routeModel),
          '/phonelog': (BuildContext context) => MobileAuthScreen(routeModel),
          '/Chat': (BuildContext context) => Chat(routeModel),
        };
}

class RouteModel {
  Map<String,bool> seen = {};
}
```

Later in your routes you want to somehow add the flag that you have seen it, and build the widget based on the flag.

```
void aboutToNavigateOut(){
  routeModel.seen['/home'] = true;
}

Widget build(context){
  return Text(routeModel.seen['/home']?"Seen":"UnSeen");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple way to fix it..

1. Use the onviewpage initialization hook to understand that user has visited the app.
2. If you want seen = true once clicked on screen or particular container then you can use host listener to know that user has visited

Comment: will you please share one example